# Media queries do not work

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm trying to get my `.sideBar` to disappear when the screen is `800px` or less. The styles are working at `480px`

I've set the viewport and have tried using `!important` to `display:none;` to override the current styles but still cant seem to get it work.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

no media queries seem to be working, does anybody know why?

JS Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/f370kxya/)

seems media queries at `max-width:800px` are not working...

head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="layout1.css"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

current styling:

```
.sideBar {
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
background:#C6C;
width:200px;
height:100%;
z-index:999;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
left: 0;
right:850px; /* Must include width of sidebar */
border-right: solid 10px #fff;
border-left: solid 10px #fff;
}
```

my `media queries` set to `800px`;

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
.centre{width:100% !important;}
.visibleArea{width:100% !important;}
.sideBar {display: none !important;}
}
```

any help would be great

here is my html for the sideBar:

```
    <!--SIDE BAR-->
<div class="sideBar">
                <div id="logo">
                    <img src="images/logo-big.png" />
                </div>

                 <div id="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Solutions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div id="newsletter">
                    <h1>NEWSLETTER</h1>  

                <div id='content'>
                    <div id="hidden-content">
                        <span class="signup">Enter your e-mail address to sign up for our monthly newsletter</span> <input class="side-mail" type="text" name="FirstName" placeholder="Email@test.com"><br> 
                        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="submit-button">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id='button'><sctrong><img src="images/more-banner.png"  /></strong></div>

                <script>
                     $("#button").click(function(){
                            $("#content").stop().slideToggle();
                            return false;
                        }); 

                $("#button").hover(function(){
                            $(this).stop().css({"cursor" : "pointer"})
                        });
                </script>

                </div>

                    <div id="barFoot">

                    <p>
                    Paxton House
                </p>

               </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Could you supply us with the HTML of your other elements and tell us what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I am trying to get the sideBar div to disapear when the screen is under 800px wide, I've used display: none; but it doesnt work, the html for .sideBar and css is in the question above

Comment: why not create a fiddle with all your code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: fiddle has been added, thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra closing bracket on line 276. Also just before the media queries, the comments have two forward slashes "//" when it should just have one.

```
//*=================================================================================*|
                                MEDIA QUERIES                               
=====================================================================================*//
```

You can read about the correct CSS comment syntax here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Comments

I have corrected your comments for you see:
https://jsfiddle.net/f370kxya/3/